# JAVAFX environmental variable return null in build.gradle.kts

Tags: gradle, javafx, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am using following `build.gradle.kts` for JavaFX app

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.30"
    id("application")
    id("org.openjfx.javafxplugin") version "0.0.9"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

javafx {
    version = "11"
    modules("javafx.controls", "javafx.fxml")
    sdk = System.getenv("JAVAFX")
    if (sdk == null || sdk2.isBlank()) {
       throw InvalidUserDataException("JAVAFX environment variable is not set. JAVAFX = $sdk")

    }
    application {
        mainClass.set("example.Main")
        applicationName = "Main"
        applicationDefaultJvmArgs = listOf(
            "--module-path=${sdk}${File.separator}lib",
            "--add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml" )

        println("applicationDefaultJvmArgs:$applicationDefaultJvmArgs")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
}
```

I have set environmental variable in .bashrc like below

```
export JAVAFX=$HOME/path/to/JavaFX/SDK
```

when I execute `echo $JAVAFX` I get the JavaFX SDK path but still I am getting `null` in `build.gradle.kts`

Tried restarting IntelliJ idea too, still the same.

Comment: You may need to also kill any Java processes that Gradle has started in the background as well. Depending on your system, open up task manager and kill and lingering Java process.

Comment: @FranciscoMateo It seems you are right, now it works fine. You may write an answer so I could accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out-of-the-box, Gradle will spawn a Java process in the background. Typically this is the [Gradle Daemon](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html), but there may be more.

So to ensure new environment variables are seen, it's best to kill any Java process that are running in the background. Depending on your system, open up task manager and kill and lingering Java process.